# Manage code across multiple SVN repositories (online hosted and internal)

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

We have a very large existing site that we're going to do a completely brand new build for. Our client has their own hosted SVN repo they've paid for which we use to commit and update our working code. As a dev shop, we have our own SVN repo internally. I'd like to get this new build of the site in both the client's hosted SVN as well as our internal SVN to share among our own team. For the original build we assumed our devs could just interface with the hosted SVN but our client has a minimal # of users so I'd like to have both SVN repos used. Is this possible at all? I'm using Tortoise SVN for my client but I can switch to any other Windows client if necessary.

(Whether I'm right or wrong here, I'm asking this question on SO thinking that coders would have run into this before. Since SO is for coders, I go where the coders are.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html) to mirror the source (client's repository) and the mirror (your internal repository).

Comment: But I'd need to run the `svnsync` command from a terminal/CLI at the hosted repo right? All we have I believe is a web GUI to see the repo and access over http to checkout, commit, update.

Comment: Seems like you can run it from anywhere... just provide the URLs of the hosted and internal repositories http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.c.init.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a git advocate, but for this purpose I'd consider git-svn. So you get client svn db into your git repository, team works with git(Tortoise Git available), then you upload your changes into subversion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking at the network usage part of it and if you are just looking at interfacing both the repositories. Then you should look as svn:externals.

If you are also looking at the network usage, you would have to setup a local mirror repository at their end using svnsync.

also check, http://whynotwiki.com/Piston